Append value in ascending order using sed
I have a configuration file where I need to append the version in ascending order. For this I have written a shell script. The value is getting appended, but the position is not correct.
Config file

[version]
        1.0.0.0, 1.0.1.0, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.3.0, 1.0.3.1, 1.0.4.0, 1.0.4.1, 1.0.5.0, 1.0.5.1, 1.0.6.0, 1.0.6.1, 1.0.6.2, 1.0.7.0, 1.0.7.1,  1.2.2.8,  1.2.2.9, 1.2.2.10, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.3.0, 1.3.0.0, 1.2.3.1, \

Suppose if I pass 1.0.7.2, then it should be appended after 1.0.7.1, basically in ascending order.
here is the shell script I wrote to achieve this
#!/bin/bash
# Define the value to append
value_to_append="$1"
# Path to the configuration file
config_file="app.config"
line_number=$(grep -n "\[version\]" "$config_file" | cut -d':' -f1)
# Append the value after the line_number
sed -i "${line_number}a \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $value_to_append," "$config_file"

With this script the value is appending at the start and not in the ascending order. What should I change in script to position the value in proper order.

please update the question to show a) the (wrong) output generated by your script and b) the (correct) expected output

sed is not the right tool for this job.

If you want insert 1.0.7.2 between 1.0.7.1 and 1.2.2.8, you have to: 1 extract list, 2 add you value 3 sort list, 4 replace line.

@JohnBollinger Some kind of sed | sort | sed: (With GNU sed): sed -e '/^\[version\]/{N;s/\n.*//;r /dev/stdin' -e \}  < <(sed <config.file '/^\[version\]/{N;s/.*\n//;s/[[:space:]]*//g;s/,/\n/g;s/\\$//g;s/\n*$/\n'"${value_to_append}"'/;p;};d'  | sort -V | xargs | sed 's/^/\o11/;s/$/ \\/;s/ /, /g') -i config.file

Perhaps, @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub.  I didn't say that sed couldn't be wrangled into doing the job.  I said it isn't the right tool for this job, and it's not.  I wouldn't use sed for this any more than I would brush my hair with a toothbrush, though both might be made to work.

Pipe to tr , \\n, look for a version number that is larger than the one you are entering, print the version being inserted into the stream, put the commas back in.

Does that backslash at the end of the list of version numbers in your input mean that the list could be continued onto the next line?

Sorting per version numbers is more difficult than it seems because 1.10 shall come after 1.9. GNU sort has a dedicated option: -V. With GNU awk and its coprocesses you can implement all this in one single awk script:
#!/bin/bash
# Path to the configuration file
config_file="app.config"
awk -v v="$1" '
  BEGIN { cmd = "sort -V" }
  go {
    n = patsplit($0, a, @/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/, s)
    a[n + 1] = v; s[n + 1] = s[n]; s[n] = ", "
    for(i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++) print a[i] |& cmd
    close(cmd, "to")
    i = 0; while(cmd |& getline) printf("%s%s", s[i++], $0)
    print s[n + 1]; go = 0; next
  }
  /^\[version\]$/ {go = 1} 1' "$config_file"

Once happy with the result you can add the awk -i inplace option to edit in place.
Explanations:

We detect the [version] line (last rule) and use the go variable to process specially only the line that follows. The other lines are printed unmodified (this is what the 1 at the end does).
The line with version numbers is first split with patsplit in versions (array a) and separators (array s).
We add the new version number at the end of array a and insert a new ,  separator in second to last position in array s. We do this because the last separator looks different from the others and you may want to preserve that.
We print all version numbers, one per line, and pipe this to the sort -V coprocess.
We close the to way of the coprocess (else sort waits forever the end of the input stream).
We read the from way of the coprocess until the end and print the sorted version numbers interleaved with the separators.

Still with GNU awk we could also take benefit of its advanced sorting capabilities that allow to provide a custom sorting function. In the following we completely avoid sort and coprocesses. The vsort function compares 2 version numbers as sort -V does, and the asort GNU awk function uses it to sort the a array:
#!/bin/bash
# Path to the configuration file
config_file="app.config"
awk -v v="$1" '
  function vsort(i1, v1, i2, v2,    n1, n2, x, y, i) {
    n1 = split(v1, x, /[.]/); n2 = split(v2, y, /[.]/)
    for(i = 1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; i++) {
      if(x[i] + 0 < y[i] + 0) return -1
      else if(x[i] + 0 > y[i] + 0) return 1
    }
    return n2 == n1 ? 0 : (n1 < n2 ? -1 : 1)
  }

  go {
    n = patsplit($0, a, @/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/, s)
    a[n + 1] = v; s[n + 1] = s[n]; s[n] = ", "
    asort(a, a, "vsort")
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) printf("%s%s", s[i], a[i + 1])
    print s[n + 1]; go = 0; next
  }
  /^\[version\]$/ {go = 1} 1' "$config_file"


Using any awk and sort -V

Get rows until version to print the first part of the file
a) Extract the version numbers, pass them to sort -V
b) Format the sorted numbers back into the original form and cat both into one file

value_to_append="1.0.7.2"

cat \
  <(awk 'set != 1{print} /version/{set=1}' file) \
  <(awk -F ',' -v val="$value_to_append" '
      set == 1{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
          sub(/ */, "", $i)
          print $i}
      print val}
      /version/{set=1}' file |
    sort -V |
    awk '{NR == 1 ? $1 = "\t"$1 : $1 = ", "$1
      printf("%s", $1)} END{print ""}')

output
Config file

[version]
    1.0.0.0, 1.0.1.0, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.3.0, 1.0.3.1, 1.0.4.0, 1.0.4.1, 1.0.5.0, 1.0.5.1, 1.0.6.0, 1.0.6.1, 1.0.6.2, 1.0.7.0, 1.0.7.1, 1.0.7.2, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.2.8, 1.2.2.9, 1.2.2.10, 1.2.3.0, 1.2.3.1, 1.3.0.0, \

Data
% cat file
Config file

[version]
        1.0.0.0, 1.0.1.0, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.3.0, 1.0.3.1, 1.0.4.0, 1.0.4.1, 1.0.5.0, 1.0.5.1, 1.0.6.0, 1.0.6.1, 1.0.6.2, 1.0.7.0, 1.0.7.1,  1.2.2.8,  1.2.2.9, 1.2.2.10, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.3.0, 1.3.0.0, 1.2.3.1, \



sed alone is not very good for this kind of operations. Assuming that all your versions are in a single line, and that line is always the exact line below the [version] tag, this script should fix it:
#!/bin/bash
# Define the value to append
value_to_append="$1"
# Path to the configuration file
config_file="app.config"
# Find list of versions, which is the line below the [version] tag
line_number=$(($(grep -n "\[version\]" "$config_file" | cut -d':' -f1) + 1))
version_list=$(sed -n "${line_number}p" "$config_file")
# Deconstruct the list from single line to multi-line, add the new version, sort the list, and reconstruct the list as single line
new_version_list=$(printf -- %s "$version_list" | sed -E -e 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/\n&/g' -e "1i ${value_to_append}, " | sort -V | tr -d '\n')
# Replace the value at line_number
sed -i -e "${line_number}i ${new_version_list}" -e "${line_number}d" "$config_file"

Side notes
The script will sort version numbers which were not sorted beforehand. In your app.config example, the version list ended with 1.2.3.0, 1.3.0.0, 1.2.3.1, which is not sorted beforehand, and will be sorted afterwards.
The script does not support multi-line lists if e.g., the version list line ends with \. This is the case in your example, so I assume you may need to deal with it.
If you run the script multiple times in a row, the new version number will be written multiple times. This can be fixed easily by replacing sort -V with sort -V | uniq but doing so will also remove existing duplicates of versions already there.

Did you try my solution commented here

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub it probably works, but it is almost impossible to modify by someone else than the author. My answer is maybe less optimal (although I haven't benchmarked it) but I believe it is significantly easier to work with by people who are not sed experts.

I don't agree, this could be written in a more readable way, anyway!

This will do what you want using any POSIX awk under the assumptions that:

You don't really have a trailing , \ at the end of your line of version numbers.
Your version numbers are all on 1 line.
No part of your version number will be more than 10 digits long (e.g. you won't have a version number like 1234567890.1.1.1).

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = ", "
    tgtVer = fmtver(add)
}

inBlock && match($0,/[^[:space:]]/) {
    indent = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        curVer = fmtver($i)
        if ( (add != "") && (curVer > tgtVer) ) {
            $i = add OFS $i
            add = ""
        }
    }
    $0 = indent $0 (add == "" ? "" : OFS add)
    inBlock = 0
}

$1 == "[version]" { inBlock=1 }

{ print }

function fmtver(ver,    out, parts, i, numParts) {
    numParts = split(ver,parts,".")
    for ( i=1; i<=numParts; i++ ) {
        out = (i > 1 ? out "." : "") sprintf("%010d", parts[i])
    }
    return out
}


$ awk -v add='1.0.7.2' -f tst.awk file
[version]
        1.0.0.0, 1.0.1.0, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.3.0, 1.0.3.1, 1.0.4.0, 1.0.4.1, 1.0.5.0, 1.0.5.1, 1.0.6.0, 1.0.6.1, 1.0.6.2, 1.0.7.0, 1.0.7.1, 1.0.7.2, 1.2.2.8, 1.2.2.9, 1.2.2.10, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.3.0, 1.3.0.0, 1.2.3.1


This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):
value=1.0.7.2
sed '/^\[version\]/{n;s/^/'"$value"', /;s/\\/&&/;s/, /&\n/g
       s/.*/echo "&"|sort -bV/e;s/\n//g}' file

Match the line beginning [version], print and fetch the next line.
Insert the value required at the front the list of versions.
Quote the last \ and insert newlines for each version.
Using substitution and the e flag to evaluate the RHS of the command, echo the versions into the sort command.
The sort command ignores leading spaces -b and sorts in version order -V.
Remove all the introduced newlines and print the result.
